# Journals comparable to MAA Monthly

Tags: reference-request

What journals are comparable in their aim and coverage with Mathematical Association of America journals such as Monthly or College Mathematics Journal. For example is there an European equivalent?  (This post reflects correction pointed out by   Will Jagy)

Comment: The two you mention are actually from the M.A.A. http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few that I can think of right now, without the resources I have at home, are below.

[**Mathematical Gazette**](http://www.m-a.org.uk/jsp/index.jsp?lnk=620)

[**Australian Mathematical Gazette**](http://www.austms.org.au/Gazette+About+the+Gazette) [more "newsey" than "mathy" though]

[**Nordisk Matematisk Tidskrift**](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000496733)

[**Elemente der Mathematik**](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/journal.php?jrn=em)

[**L’Enseignement Mathématique**](http://www.unige.ch/math/EnsMath/EM_en/welcome.html)

[**Pokroky Matematiky, Fyziky a Astronomie**](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/140123) [might be more related to [*Mathematical Intelligencer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Intelligencer), however]